# How do I change the color of histogram bars?

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram

I'm sure there's an answer to this somewhere, but I can't find it anywhere.

How do I color histogram bars by another set of data such that the bars look like this...

[image]

The only difference would be that the bars are different heights.

Comment: Please post your attempt and a data sample to reproduce it.

Comment: I found this picture online. It's not my code @ImSo3K

Comment: To help you solve the issue, you need to at least provide some data for us to use, and a failed attempt of yours won't hurt either.

Comment: Please note, that's a bar chart, not a histogram.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use the matplotlib module, there is a color parameter for the bar chart. In this parameter you can change what the color is. Here is an example of some code from the matplotlib.org that I have edited to show this to you.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


labels = ['G1', 'G2', 'G3', 'G4', 'G5']
men_means = [20, 35, 30, 35, 27]
women_means = [25, 32, 34, 20, 25]
men_std = [2, 3, 4, 1, 2]
women_std = [3, 5, 2, 3, 3]
width = 0.35       # the width of the bars: can also be len(x) sequence

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.bar(labels, men_means, width, yerr=men_std, label='Men', color = 'blue')
ax.bar(labels, women_means, width, yerr=women_std, bottom=men_means,
       label='Women', color = 'pink')

ax.set_ylabel('Scores')
ax.set_title('Scores by group and gender')
ax.legend()

plt.show()
```

This code will result in the graph linked

[Bar Chart Color Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IX4Ua.png)

There are a lot of different colors to choose from. Here is a link to the colors available with matplotlib.

https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/color/named_colors.html